# BigInteger(line.getBytes()) and Files.readAllBytes() giving different outputs

Tags: java, string, file, binary, bit

I am trying to implement huffman compression algorithm in Java.I could sucessfully compress a string and write it to a file(say 'compressed.java'). Now I am working on the second part in which, I need to uncompress 'compressed.java' to the original file.

I need to read each line in the file as bits. So when I had a very small 'compressed.java' file, I used `Files.readAllBytes(path)` and then used `String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0')`, to convert the file content to a string of bits and then parsed bit by bit and I could decompress successfully. But when I had a very large 'compressed.java' (11 MB) file, `Files.readAllBytes(path)` is taking so much time. So I thought of reading each line and then converting it into a stream of bytes and then parsing bit by bit. So I read each line using `BufferedReader.readLine` and then used new `BigInteger(line.getBytes()).toString(2)` to convert to a binary string. But this string is different from what I got earlier.

Can you please tell me where I am making the mistake.

Comment: It is not possible to read files "as bits", the smallest unit you can get with Java is Byte - you may split each byte up into 8 bits yourself and possibly do your own thing but thats about it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I cannot read files as bits. If I have a small file, using Files.readAllBytes(path) is working fast and I am able to uncompress the content of the compressed file. But if the compressed file is a big one, Files.readAllBytes(path) is taking so much time. What I am looking for, is a way to read File as chunks of bytes. But still, the problem is that some of my characters in the original file would be residing in two different bytes in the compressed file. That also needs to be taken care.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)
I think you need to discard your current task and start with java programming basics first - it isnt possible to achieve something complex like compression algorithms without deep insight into your chosen language

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` removes the line termination characters. It also returns chars, not bytes. You're comparing apples and oranges. If you want all the bytes, use an `InputStream.read(byte[])` loop.

Comment: The line I read using `readLine()` is converted into bytes using line.getBytes().

Comment: That doesn't help with the other issues.